# Netcore - Apply configurations to framework classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core

I have a set of libraries, which I want to move from PCL to netcore. With the move I want to streamline the DI system and update some internal workings.

One of the things I want to add is configuration for internal objects, much like in Asp.Net Core (i.e. `services.AddMvc(opt => { /* Options Stuff*/ });`).
My current service collection extension looks like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCore(this IServiceCollectionserviceCollection, Action<HttpClientOptions> options)
{
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
    serviceCollection.Configure(options);
    return serviceCollection;
}
```

And the configuration class looking like this:

```
public sealed class HttpClientOptions
{
    public HttpMessageHandler MessageHandler { get; set; }

    // Remaining properties omitted for brevity
}
```

However I'm asking myself, how I can apply the configuration to `HttpClient`, since it's a framework class and I can'T modify it to take the options via constructor injection.

Is there a way to set this, or do I have to rethink my configuration approach?

Comment: "I want to move from PCL to netcore". No, you want to move from PCL to .NET Standard.

Comment: Your libraries should be free of any dependency on a DI Container. Read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Comment: The libraries won't have any dependency on a particular DI Framework. Anything regarding DI will be made available by (optional) extension methods.

Comment: But if those libraries are just part of your solution (so not reusable libraries that you ship as NuGet packages), they shouldn't do any object composition at all. You should centralize object composition in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: Also note that if your library depends upon `IServiceCollection`, you _are_ using a DI library.

Comment: Again: I don't know where you are getting it from that my libraries are depending on any DI container, or that I'm not composing the composition as close to the entry point as possible. Everything you said, I'm already doing (in a way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serviceCollection.AddSingleton()` has an overload that takes a `Func<IServiceProvider, HttpClient>` factory.

So, you could potentially do something along the lines of:

```
serviceCollection
    .AddSingleton<HttpClient>((serviceCollectionInstance) => {
        var myOptions = serviceCollectionInstance.GetRequiredService<MyHttpClientOptions>();
        return new HttpClient(myOptions);
    });
```

Or even

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MyHttpClientFactory>(); // <-- your very own factory class that creates arbitrarily complex options
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(_ => _.GetRequiredService<MyHttpClientFactory>().CreateHttpClient());
```

If you really wanted to go overboard, you could even write your very own extension method to achieve the fluent configuration style:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddHttpClient(this IServiceCollection @this, Action<HttpClientOptions> configure = null)
    {
        var options = new HttpClientOptions();

        if (configure != null)
        {
            configure(options);
        }

        @this.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(options);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(opts => {
    opts.HttpMessageHandler = // etc
});
```

Comment: I knew I overlooked something! Thanks for reminding me factory patterns exists.